# Maven overlay with war not generated by maven

Tags: maven, integration, war

I'm pretty new to Maven, so I apologize if this is a newbie question. We are trying to integrate a 3rd-party app into ours. This 3rd-party functionality is delivered to us as a war file. As part of this integration, I want to add some extra jars and and a properties file. Googling around, I discovered [overlays](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html). However, in all the examples I've seen, it looks the the wars that are being overlayed, were themselves generated by Maven, and thus Maven can figure out dependencies, conflicts, etc. between the two. I'm just wondering if there's a way for me to overlay this 3rd-party war with this extra stuff I want. If so, what would that look like in the pom.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work, the WAR file you want to overlay has to be provided in a Maven repository. Either a public one, like the central Maven one, or the JBoss one, or in a private one that you or your company hosts. In the latter case, you can upload it there yourself, even if it was not generated by Maven.

Dependencies will work better if there's a proper POM file for the WAR, but it will also work without one. Without a POM, the WAR file will basically be unzipped and your changes are applied to it by copying in your content. You can somewhat customize this by using the `dependentWarExcludes` and `warSourceExcludes` tags.

Please post the *war plugin* configuration from your POM if you require more help.